# android application not found on setting its permission

Tags: android

When I set permission in AndroidManifest.xml then my app does not launch even if it is installed on my device.When I click on it a toast message appears saying "Application not found".When I remove this permission it works totally fine.I am using android studio 1.5.1 ,my minSdkVersion is 8 and targetSdkVersion is 23.Please suggest where is the problem with my permission.My AndroidManifest.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.permissionexampleboom">
<permission
    android:name="com.example.android.permissionexampleboom.PERMI"
    android:label="@string/boom"
    android:description="@string/descr">
</permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:permission="com.example.android.permissionexampleboom.PERMI">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: I was following a tutorial where they gave the name "PERMI" randomly.So should I specify it somewhere?

Comment: just remove it.. its unnecessary

Comment: I have removed it but then also the same problem.

Comment: did you solve this yet ?

Comment: No not yet,I am still having the same problem .